# How to use map function to save a list of dataframes to the desired path using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a code written using for loop to save the dataframes present in a list (Date is the name of the list) to the specified path

```
for Dates in Date:
    if Dates.empty:
        pass
    else:
        PATH = f'C:/Users/Desktop/' + Dates.iloc[0]['Col1'] + '/' + Dates.iloc[0]['Col2'] + '/'
        if not os.path.exists(PATH):
            os.makedirs(PATH)
        Day = Dates.iloc[0]["DAY"]
        Dates = Dates.drop(['Col1', 'Col2'], axis=1)
        Dates.to_csv(os.path.join(PATH,f'{Day}.csv'),index=False)
```

However, this code executes for a long time. Can anyone please help me how to modify the above code using map function to reduce the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that your for loop works correctly you could use a map function as follow:

```py
import pandas as pd

def save_dataframe(Dates: pd.DataFrame):
    if not Dates.empty:
        PATH = f'C:/Users/Desktop/' + Dates.iloc[0]['Col1'] + '/' + Dates.iloc[0]['Col2'] + '/'
        if not os.path.exists(PATH):
            os.makedirs(PATH)
        Day = Dates.iloc[0]["DAY"]
        Dates = Dates.drop(['Col1', 'Col2'], axis=1)
        Dates.to_csv(os.path.join(PATH,f'{Day}.csv'),index=False)

my_map = map(save_dataframe, Date) # generation of your map
list(my_map) # excutions of the map
```

Comment: The for loop works correctly. When I replace the for loop with your code, I get this . <map at 0x2751beeeb30>
The folder specified in the path is not created

Comment: in which line give the error

Comment: There is no error. The code runs without any error. But the csv files are not getting saved to the path

Comment: ok, map returns an generator and does not process the actions until you asked for it, I update the answer, but you only need to add something like list(my_map)

Comment: @Aishwarya let me know if that works. here you have a link to a page explaining what is a generator https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

Comment: @Aishwarya, here you have another link https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/ LEt me now if its clear